# Flutter Dart vs Python websock. I get empty messages on the server

Tags: python, flutter, websocket

I am creating a flutter application that talk to a python backend,
when I call in Flutter `channel.sink.add ('msg')` on the server, I get an empty string in  data`def on_data_receive(client, data):`

Flutter code client(web_socket_channel 2.1.0):

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
...

 channels = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('wss://192.168.1.71:4321'));
 channels.stream.listen((data) {
      print(data);
    });
 void sendMessage(msg) {
   channels.sink.add(msg);
  }
...
```

Python code server(websock 1.0.4):

```
from websock import WebSocketServer
...
def on_data_receive(client, data):
    try:
        j_data = json.loads(data)
...
```

Please tell me, what could be the problem?

Comment: have you made your main function `async`

Comment: python?? dart??

Comment: Main fun in dart code

Comment: main func not async.

Comment: make it `async`

Comment: I tried it, the result is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, the problem is solved.

Comment: Hey ! I would recommend you answering this question yourself which would help future developers  :)